# How to query whether SSH is available under Debian?

Tags: ssh, installation, debian, firewall

I'm trying to implement ssh server under a custom Debian-based installation, which has no GUI, and yet no ssh access. How can I know whether SSH is installed, and how can I know whether the firewall actually allows it or not ?

Comment: Wait, you mean you can't access the server AT ALL?

Comment: You don't even have console access?

Comment: I do have console access, but when I try to connect via SSH, I get a "Connection refused". Also, I cannot seem to find SSH, and the depots don't seem to be configured so I can retrieve SSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether the firewall allows it (assuming you're using iptables) write `iptables -l` (with root, otherwise put `sudo` in front).

As to whether the ssh-server is installed or not (assuming you're using packages) do `aptitude search openssh-server` and check the status marker next to the name.

If you're outside the server, simply try to connect to the IP on port 22 to verify/check that it is open :)

Comment: OP states no GUI (ha!) or SSH access :P

Answer (score 0):

> Ask the server administrator ;)

Otherwise it just seems shady with the details you've given us.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have console access, `dpkg -l openssh-server` will tell you whether or not the SSH server package is installed.
2. Running `pgrep sshd` will return the process ID of the SSH daemon if it is running.